# Quarkus camel- how to mock a route's return value in Camel 3?

Tags: java, testing, apache-camel, quarkus

I am having the darndest time trying to replicate some mock/advice functionality that worked in Camel 2, but cannot find an analogous path in Camel 3. My goal is to completely replace the route with an object I provide, ideally not running the original route at all.

Route:

```java
from("direct:someRoute")
.id("someRoute")
.log(...)
.toD("http://some.call.com/request")
.id("someCall")
.log(...)
.end()
```

Camel 2:

```java
RouteDefinition rd = this.camelContext.getRouteDefinition("someRoute");

rd.adviceWith(this.camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveById("someCall")
            .replace()
            .setBody(constant("{}"));
    }
});
this.camelContext.start();
```

This works in camel2, but noticing there is no way to get a `RouteDefinition` from the context in 3, along with no `adviceWith` on a `Route` object.

I have also tried with `AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, route, a->{})`, but `a->{}` lacks RouteBuilder functions like `constant`.

Comment: .setBody().constant("{}");

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to make it an answer.
Odd that I couldn't find an example of that, could be bad at googling